# getScheduler() and getDefaultScheduler() which one to use and when (Quartz Scheduler API)

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

While reading Quartz Scheduler documentation, I came across two different ways to get an instance of Scheduler for which I am not clear which one to use when.

1. `getScheduler()`
2. `getDefaultScheduler()`

i know that `getDefaultScheduler` will simply create an instance of `StdSchedulerFactory` while `getScheduler()` will init the scheduler based on the configuration provided to it.

Can any one help me to understand the use cases where each is most applicable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

getDefaultScheduler() is static, and will return the scheduler instance that is defined by the properties file named "quartz.properties" in the class path, or if none of those, then the default properties bundled into the quartz jar.

getScheduler() is not static, and returns the scheduler defined by the properties the scheduler factory is initialized with - which if none, results in the same behavior as getDefaultScheduler(), but, the factory may have been initialized with specific properties or the name of a specific property file.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a compulsive enough reason and you want to write a scheduler use defaultScheduler().